# Как запостить несколько фотографий в facebook?

Tags: python, django, facebook-api

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой постинга нескольких фотографий

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=%s&published=false&url=%s' % (user.fb_token, img)
```

С api fb не сильно знаком, уже два дня мучаюсь в поисках решения, может есть метод в котором можно перечислить ссылки на фото или их id и все это вместе запостить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118178/post-picture-to-facebook-using-python

Comment: я не использую sdk, поэтому ваш ответ не подходит, спасибо за участие